# Jitsi Meet giving error "Program type already present: com.facebook.jni.HybridData$Destructor"

Tags: android, react-native, jitsi-meet

I'm trying to run jitsi meet in my android application but I keep getting the following build error:

> Program type already present: com.facebook.jni.HybridData$Destructor
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   com.facebook.jni.HybridData$Destructor, sources=[Unknown source file],
>   tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

I do use facebook conceal library to encrypt files in my application so I'm assuming that react-native is reusing code used in conceal.

Any ideas on how can I get rid of that error?

Answer (score 0):

So both jitsi and conceal use facebook native libraries and that is why they conflict. Both libraries have the same path. There are two ways to solve this issue:

1. Rebuild conceal library and change the path of the native facebook library. That can get very messy since the documentation on rebuilding is partially missing. I spent couple of days trying to rebuild but got stuck and went with solution 2. I can share what I went through in order to rebuilt and where I got stuck if anyone needs it.
2. Downgrade conceal to 1.1.3. You shouldn't have any problems with that since it's the exact same code (except that 1.1.3 all of it written in Java) so if you already have a released app that has files that were encrypted with v2.0.1, the downgrade would still decrypt the files.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/facebook/conceal/issues/196) to the github issue.